# Android - The correct way to reshape a edittext box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-drawable

I am working on making an Editbox look better by having this code:

```
<EditText 
      android:id="@+id/edittext"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
      android:padding="5dip"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
      android:hint="@string/hint"
      android:textColor="#000"/>
```

Please note the `background` property above using is a shape `rounded_edittext` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="5dp"/>

<solid android:color="#ccc" />

</shape>   

</item>

<item android:bottom="0.5dp">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>   
</item>

</layer-list>
```

after applying this shape, the edittext box looks prettier than before, but **I lost the "I" input indicator.** When I tap on the edittext box and input something, there's no input indicator show up that made feel really bad. I was wondering if this is a correct way of reshape an edittext box, or is there any other workaround that can reshape the box same like this but keep the "I" input indicator.

Comment: i don't have an answer but i also wants to know what happened i might encounter this problem.if you type something does it appear?

Comment: @HakHak Hi Yes it shows everything I typed in except the input indicator...

Comment: just a guess i really dont know maybe because of this   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />?try 000000

Comment: @HakHak yeah seems you are right, the input indicator has the same color as the background so looks like it doesn't show. The follow up question is, how should I change the input indicator color?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write OnClickListener on that EditText and Try this code in your activity

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    et.requestFocus();
    }
});
```